# Syntax error when writing a trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I'm trying to write a trigger for calculating the average rating of an institution.
The idea is this:
When an impressin is added to the table, the average score should be calculated using the `AVG` function. Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'ratein_up' AFTER INSERT ON 'impressin'
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    SET @new_rat:=(SELECT AVG(Rating) FROM impressin);
    UPDATE feed-point SET OLD.AverageRating = @new_rat 
    WHERE id= NEW.idFeedPoint;
    END
```

Indicates an error in the line:`UPDATE feed-point SET OLD.AverageRating = @new_rat WHERE id= NEW.idFeedPoint;`

Comment: There are so many errors in the code that I'm voting to close as "too broad".  You are using single quotes incorrectly around identifiers, you are doing some sort of subtraction after the `update`, you are attempting to update a row in the source table in an *after update* trigger.

Comment: This is not a minus, this is the name of my table.Single quotes formed PHP MyAdmin

Comment: Are you sure you even want a trigger for this derived data?

Comment: Извините за неприятность, я отредактировал триггер и протестировал его, он работает правильно. Необходимо было ввести название таблицы в кавычки. Исправленная строка: UPDATE 'feed-point' SET AverageRating = @new_rat WHERE id = NEW.idFeedPoint;

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for the trouble, I edited the trigger and tested, it works correctly.
It was necessary to take the name of the table into quotes.
Corrected line

```
UPDATE `feed-point` SET AverageRating = @new_rat WHERE id= NEW.idFeedPoint;
```